# Compressing with GZIP in c# and decompressing in python fails

Tags: python, c#, gzip

I have a flow where some data (like an image/video) gets compressed using GZip like this:

```cs
await using var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
await using var compressionStream = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress);

await compressionStream.WriteAsync(payload);
await compressionStream.FlushAsync();

outputStream.Position = 0;
return outputStream.ToArray()
```

The above code is not from my team but it can be changed if needed.

If I get the output into a base64 string and test decompressing it with this simple code, it works perfectly:

```cs
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("H4sIAAAAAAAACirOz01VKEmtKAEAAAD//w=="); // "some text"
using var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
using var ds = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress);
using var output = new MemoryStream();
ds.CopyTo(output);
ds.Flush();

var result = output.ToArray();
```

However, my requirement is to get the compressed payload in a python script and decompress it before passing it to another system. I'm not at all familiar with python, so I made this very simple script:

```py
import base64
import gzip

encodedBase64 = "H4sIAAAAAAAACirOz01VKEmtKAEAAAD//w=="
decodedBytes = base64.standard_b64decode(encodedBase64)
decompressedBytes = gzip.decompress(decodedBytes)
```

The above fails with: `EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached`

I have of course done research and found posts like [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52478874/how-to-decompress-text-in-python-that-has-been-compressed-with-gzip) but nothing has helped (for example, using that answer fails with `gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'\x00\x00')`. Other attempts have yielded different gzip errors.

Comment: Can you check if the generate gzip file is valid or not? [This](https://superuser.com/a/1068543/961093) should work Windows, Unix and Linux

Comment: (Just a note: you're not disposing any of your Streams before reading the compressed/decompressed output. I don't think that's making any difference as you *are* explicitly flushing them first, so I don't think that's related to your problem, but as a matter of best practice...)

Comment: Try to narrow down where the issue is: compare the decoded bytes in both Python and C# (`decodedBytes` vs `bytes`), see if they're the same

Comment: I rewrote your code, disposing the streams when I'd normally dispose them, and got a different (slightly longer) result: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bbriL7 . Both approaches decode the same in C#, but I wonder whether the longer one contains the footer that Python is expecting...

Comment: Indeed, `Flush` [doesn't call `_deflater.Finish()`](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.Compression/System/IO/Compression/DeflateZLib/DeflateStream.cs,495), but `Dispose` [does](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.Compression/System/IO/Compression/DeflateZLib/DeflateStream.cs,522). I guess that makes sense -- there's a footer which needs to be added right at the end of compression, and `Flush` might be called multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GzipStream` needs to be disposed before you read its output. Gzip has a footer which needs to be added to the end of the stream, and this is [added by `Dispose()`](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.Compression/System/IO/Compression/DeflateZLib/DeflateStream.cs,522) (and also by `Close()`) but [not by `Flush()`](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.Compression/System/IO/Compression/DeflateZLib/DeflateStream.cs,495). I guess this makes sense, as `Flush()` may be called multiple times during the encoding process, so it would be the wrong place to add a footer.

I rewrote your code to dispose objects at the appropriate points, and also got rid of the `async` since you're dealing with purely synchronous operations:

```
public static string Encode()
{
    var payload = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("some text");
    using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var compressionStream = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            compressionStream.Write(payload);
        }
        var result = outputStream.ToArray();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
    }   
}
```

This produces the output

```
H4sIAAAAAAAAAyvOz01VKEmtKAEAur26TwkAAAA=
```

Which is slightly longer than the output you saw, suggesting that it contains the footer that Python is expecting. It still decodes to the same result, at least in .NET, however.

It's interesting that .NET's `GzipStream` is robust to the footer missing, but `Python`'s version is not.

Comment: Python uses the same implementation as `gzip`, and using `gzip` from the command line or from 7-zip both fail the test. It's interesting that .NET can still handle it, and it can also handle some missing headers too it seems. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, since the footer contains a CRC I'd expect .NET to be failing if it's missing as well